# Is UIEventKit the best way to make a custom alarm/reminder iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

My new iphone application will let the user to create alarms/reminders and set a time and date to fire as an alarm. I will store some data about each alarm like title, details, alarm type any maybe other information.

Is is better to use UIEventKit or is there any better way? I don't want to mix alarms or reminders with the iPhone calendar. The best example for that is the new iOS 5 Reminders application I'd like to do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Are you absolutely sure there isn't an app which can already do what you have in mind?

[App Store Review Guideline](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) 2.11 states:

> Apps that duplicate apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra apps.

Searching the App Store for `alarm` in my region (Australia) gives **865** results for iPad and **2914** results for iPhone. `reminder` gives **215** iPad and **1120** iPhone apps. A LOT of these are free apps.

Make sure your app is going to provide a unique feature set first. Once you do that, check out [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for presenting the user with a reminder which is separate from the iPhone calendar.

Comment: thanks for tge answer. Yes I'm going to do it even if you found a million of alarms apps.

Comment: My app has many features and tgis is a part of them. It will not be a duplicate.